# Ionic Components are not destroyed after navigation to another page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am currently working on legacy code where the project is an Angular 6, Ionic 4 hybrid. All the feature modules are being lazy loaded.

The problem is that after navigating to another page I can see on the memory tab on nav tool that the previous page is still there and the `ngOnDestroy` hasn't really been fired.

To give you more details, my app-routing-module is:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { routes } from './app.routes';


 @NgModule({
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { enableTracing: false, useHash: false  
 })],
  exports: [RouterModule],
 })
 export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

My routes are:

```
  export const routes: Routes = [
     { 
       path: '', redirectTo: '/home',
       pathMatch: 'full' 
     },
     { 
     path: 'accounts',
     loadChildren: 
    '../pages/accounts/accounts.page.module#AccountsPageModule',
      canActivate: [AuthGuardService] 
     },
     {
     path: 'administration',
     loadChildren:      
'../pages/administration/administration.page.module#AdministrationPageModule' 
     },
    { 
     path: 'bookings',
     loadChildren: 
     '../pages/bookings/bookings.page.module#BookingsPageModule',
     canActivate: [AuthGuardService],

  },
```

and in the app.component.html, together with a `ion-menu` structure the router:

```
 <ion-router-outlet id="content" swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-router-outlet>
```

And finally in the navbar component on every link I use the `[routerLink]="['/something']"` directive of the router.

The navigation is working properly. The issue is that after some time the site is very slow as it still has every component, page and module in memory even though the user is navigated to another page and Angular should have destroyed the previous.

I am using:

- Angular: 6.1.7
- Ionic: 4.1.2

Comment: I believe this is related to this issue(s) here -> 
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24962
https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/24987

Comment: hmm not quite.I tried to use router events and call ngOnDestroy but again the page component and the feature module will still be on memory

Comment: Yeah that's interesting. Since I'm on the browser I don't have an issue with needing to "clean up" or remove loaded modules and components. 

Did you try the OnDestroy for both Components and Modules?

Comment: I am also on the browser.You mean that you keep everything in memory?Wouldn't that cause a performance issue?                                                                                            I also tried that to the modules but unfortunately ngOnDestroy is not called there either.

Comment: I honestly don't have a memory issue. After changing the preloadingStrategy to NoPreloading the application initial load time decreased significantly. I use a lot of tabs in my app and each tab is a component. Well I add a *ngIf to the component that will be true if the tab is clicked. This will remove the template from the DOM and allow Garbage collection to do its thing on all other tabs not currently in view.

Comment: i managed to find a hack around it.I created  a service which has a behavior subject that emits the current page on view.Then every page which is listening on that observable checks the current page and with an ngIf directive at least i remove the html elements inside every page.After i did that when i navigate to 2,3 pages i can see a list of 3 ngOnDestroy from the previous page..Weirddddd.Nice idea by the way for the tabs..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally figured out why.

- *I completely removed ionic from the application and use only Angular router for* navigation.

Now ngOnDestroy is being called every time i navigate to another page and the page itself is removed from the DOM.

Comment: Thats correct. When you use the Ionic navigation you can use other lifecyclehooks. See: https://blog.ionicframework.com/navigating-lifecycle-events/

Comment: Despite ngOnDestroy being called, the component still stays there and prevents going back in history. Did you solve this?

Answer (score 25):

Ionic cache pages on navigation and destroy and init hooks doesn't work.

If you need to do some actions on navigation you need to use [ionic-router-outlet](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/router-outlet#properties) hooks.

- `ionViewWillEnter`   - Fired when the component being routed to is about to
  animate in.
- `ionViewDidEnter` - Fired when the component being routed to
  has animated in.
- `ionViewWillLeave`   - Fired when the component being routed from is
  about to animate.
- `ionViewDidLeave` - Fired when the    component being routed from has
  animated.

You don't need to use any interfaces like `OnInit` or `OnDestroy`. You can use a hook.

Example:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent {
  ionViewDidLeave() {
    // Do actions here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

I am using ionic 4 and angular. What worked for me is  adding { replaceUrl: true } to navigation

```
this.router.navigate([page.url], { replaceUrl: true });
```

or on template

```
<a [routerLink]="page.url" replaceUrl="true">...
```

Comment: Hi, "this.router.navigate([page.url], { replaceUrl: true });".  This worked to navigate as expected.On navigating to other screen, it started to cause issues with the clicks are not working(Page might be hidden under any layer).Not sure about the reasons of it.

Answer (score 7):

If you use Ionic routing (`<ion-router-outlet>` and `{ provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }`), as mentioned in the other answer, Pages are cached and navigating to other page, `ngOnDestroy` is not being called.

If you dont want that, use `navigateRoot()` from NavContrller:

`this.navController.navigateRoot(['some-route']);`

And users will not be able to swipe back to the previous page.

Comment: Would have been nice if Ionic could have provided an option to use navigateRoot when using the ion-tabs component

Comment: Why is there no documentation on navController? I can't find it and it's working for me.

Answer (score 1):

`replaceUrl` would affect back button navigation if you set its `defaultHref` to another page than the previous one

Answer (score 0):

For me `ionViewWillEnter` helped as I am navigating out from a page while I needed to change the view of the page I am navigated to.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have a `<video-player>` custom component that doesn't get destroyed when I navigate to the next page.

So imagine I have a video player route like `/video/videoId1`.

This page is called `VideoComponent` and has a simplified template like the following:

```
<ion-content>
   <video-player [src]="videoUrl"></video-player>
   <ion-button>Next</ion-button>
</ion-content>
```

This page functions similar to a video player going through a video playlist. So the `<ion-button>` is simply navigating to the next video in the playlist, which is essentially navigating to the same component with a different URL param like:

```
/video/videoId2
/video/videoId3
```

When navigation forward happens, the previous player still keeps on playing the video. This just keeps on adding so if we are viewing the fourth video on the playlist, the last three videos are still playing in the background.

I have tried `ngOnDestroy`, `ionViewWillLeave` and `ionViewDidLeave` on `VideoPlayerComponent` but nothing gets called. So I just ended up hard-coding the code to force stop the player on the `<ion-button>` click handler.

If I put the `ngOnDestroy`, `ionViewWillLeave` or `ionViewDidLeave` on the parent `VideoComponent`, it gets called correctly but from there I don't have access to the methods in the `VideoPlayerComponent` component. I probably can use Subject or Input to pass data into the child component but it seems overkill for a basic component lifecycle handling.